# Сокет засыпает навсегда

Tags: c++, сокет, winsock

Есть клиент и сервер. Клиент подключается к серверу, сервер производит длительные вычисления и возвращает ответ.
Код сервера y.y.y.y:1234

```
SOCKET Socket = accept(Listen, NULL, NULL);
Sleep(1000 * 60 * 6); // виновник
int error = send(Socket, "Hello", 6, 0);
printf("Send size: %d\nWSA Error: %d", error, WSAGetLastError());
closesocket(Socket);
```

Код клиента z.z.z.z

```
SOCKET Socket = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
sockaddr_in Address;
Address.sin_family = AF_INET;
Address.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr ("y.y.y.y");
Address.sin_port = htons (1234);
connect(Socket, (sockaddr *)&Address, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
char buf[6];
int error = recv(Socket, buf, 6, 0); // тут проблема
printf("%s", buf);
closesocket(Socket);
```

Если соединение происходит в локальной сети (через роутер), то данная программа работает. Но если сервер находится в глобальной сети, то сервер отправляет 6 байт, возвращает ошибку WSA 0 и продолжает работу, а клиент навсегда засыпает на инструкции `recv`.
Пытался в клиенте писать проверки:

```
int RecvTimeout = 1000 * 4;
setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&RecvTimeout, sizeof(int));
do {
    recv(Socket, buf, 6, 0);
} while (WSAGetLastError() == WSAETIMEDOUT);
```

или

```
timeval time; time.tv_usec = 0; time.tv_sec = 1;
fd_set read, except;
do {
    FD_ZERO(&read); FD_ZERO(&except);
    FD_SET(Socket, &read); FD_SET(Socket, &except);
    select(0, &read, 0, &except, &time);
} while (!FD_ISSET(Socket, &except) && !FD_ISSET(Socket, &read));
```

Оба цикла крутятся бесконечно.
При отправке сообщения сервером роутер пишет

> Blocked outgoing TCP packet from y.y.y.y:1234 to
>   z.z.z.z:7323 as PSH:ACK received but there is no active
>   connection

Подозреваю, что данная проблема имеет место быть не только в Windows. Скорее всего кто-то(провайдер?) следит за активностью соединения и закрывает его без предупреждения. Что происходит, кто виноват и как быть в такой ситуации? UDP не предлагать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема - в вашем роутере, точнее в его реализации PNAT. Пока сервер ждет, роутер успевает "забыть" про соединение. UDP в этой ситуации и не поможет - про него роутер точно так же забудет.

Сделать тут можно только одну вещь - не засыпать надолго. Надо добавить в ваш протокол "пустые" пакеты, которые нужны для поддержания и проверки соединения. Одна из сторон должны их регулярно отправлять.

Comment: Данный код помог 'while (1) { send(Socket, "", 1, 0); recv(Socket, buf, 6, 0); if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAETIMEDOUT) break;}'. Но теперь представим, что у одной из сторон в этот момент пропал интернет. Сервер снова отправит сообщение без ошибок, но клиент войдёт в бесконечный цикл. Мне просто интересно, как выявить это "мёртвое" соединение.

Comment: @SuperDimon007 Вы слишком часто отправляете сообщение в этом цикле, поставьте хоть какую-нибудь задержку :) Что же до потери интернета - в этом случае на сервере рано или поздно возникнет ошибка отправки.

Comment: У меня стоит большая задержка функции `recv`. Через некоторое время цикл действительно выходит, но куда несколько раз успешно уходят нули функцией `send`? Firewall уверяет, что клиент успешно шлёт пакеты по байту. Данные уходят в системный буфер, и, если пакеты не передаются через некоторое время, то соединение сбрасывается?

Comment: @SuperDimon007 примерно тек и есть

Comment: @SuperDimon007 а задержку все-таки поставьте.Достаточно передавать пакеты где-то раз в минуту для нормального поддержания соединения.